# How to check null value within TempData Razor MVC that written inside js code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, tempdata

I'm Trying to check null value within TempData Razor MVC that written inside javascript code, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

whether TempData value is null or not, the condition is always true

```
if ('@TempData["Error"]' != null) {
    alert("Problem" + '\n' + "@TempData["error"]");
} else {
    alert("The file Uploaded Successfully");    
}
```

How i can check?
if there are alternatives, please let me know.

thanks.

Edit:

The code above is part of JQuery ajax request code.

```
 <script>
    $body = $("body");
    $(document).on({
        ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); },
        ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#upload").click(function () {
            var data = new FormData();

            //Add the Multiple selected files into the data object
            var files = $("#files").get(0).files;
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append("files" + i, files[i]);
            }
            //data.append("id", '');
            data.append("id", '@Model.NoteID');
            //Post the data (files) to the server

            if (files.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "@Url.Action("Upload","Files")",
                    data:data,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if ('@TempData["Error"]' != null) {
                            alert("Problem" + '\n' + "@TempData["error"]");
                        } else {
                            alert("file uploaded successfully");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Fail");
                    },
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this in a separate js file ?

Comment: `@TempData["Error"]` shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: No, it is inside HTML page. Actually the code above is part of JQuery ajax request, i will update the post.

Comment: Refer updated answer based on your edit and the fact this is inside an ajax call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quoting the value, so if `@TempData["Error"]` is `null`, it translates to a empty string. You could check it using `.length` but it would be better to use

```
var error = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TempData["Error"]))
if (error) {
    alert("Problem" + '\n' + error);
} else {
    alert("The file Uploaded Successfully");
}
```

---

Based on the revised context of the question, your using this inside an ajax call. Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view, so `@TempData["Error"]` returns the value when when the page is first rendered. Just because you may be setting the value of `TempData` in the `Upload()` method does not update it.

Your method should be returning json containing the error so that you can then display it in the success callback. For example, your method might be

```
public ActionResult Upload(...)
{
    return Json(null); // to indicate success, or
    return Json("oops, something went wrong);
}
```

and then in the ajax callback

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response) {
        alert(response);
    } else {
        alert("The file Uploaded Successfully");
    }
```

Comment: It works, but when the request ends successfully with return json(null) .. it returns 'Fail'. it goes to  error:function(){alert("Fail");}

Comment: That should not happen unless you throw an exception (although it does with the `$.getJSON()` method). You can always do something like `return Json(true);` for success and `return Json( new { Error = "your error message" });` and then in the script - `if (response.Error) { alert(response.Error); } else { ... }`

Comment: And did you happen to add `dataType: 'json',` (which would also cause the error - if so just delete it)

Comment: I added dataType:'json', then delete it .. same problem happened. fortunately, i found good solution for me. thank you so much for your help.